# Expand the lower two 32-bit floats of an xmm register to the whole xmm register

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

What is the most efficient way in Intel x86 assembly to do the following operation (*a*, *b* are 32-bit floats):

From `xmm1: [-, -, a, b]` to `xmm1: [a, a, b, b]`

I could not find any useful instructions.
My idea is to copying *a* and *b* to other registers and then shift the `xmm1` register 4 bytes and move *a* or *b* to the lowest 4 bytes.

Comment: Are you doing integer computations or are these floating point computations?  Peter Cordes' code is correct for floating point, but if you are working in the integer domain, you  want `punpckldq` instead.  This avoids an FP/integer transition penalty.

Comment: Thanks i want to do for floating points

Comment: BTW, you might want to use intrinsics instead of hand-written asm, if you're starting a new project and especially if you didn't already know how to find an answer to this question yourself (because that hints that you probably don't know better than a compiler in terms of other choices, too).  I added a section about that to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `unpcklps  xmm1, xmm1` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/unpcklps) to interleave the low elements from a register with itself:
low element -> bottom 2, 2nd lowest to high 2.

You could instead use `shufps` but that wouldn't be any better in this case, and would need an immediate byte.  To copy-and-shuffle, you could use `pshufd`, but on a few CPUs that integer instruction is slower between FP instructions (but it's still typically better than a `movaps` + `unpcklps`. There's either no bypass latency, or it's 1 cycle and movaps would cost the same latency but also some throughput resources.  Except Nehalem where bypass latency would be 2 cycles.  I don't think any CPUs with mov-elimination have bypass latency for shuffles, but maybe some AMD do.)

---

If you were having trouble finding the right shuffle instruction, consider writing it in C and seeing if clang can turn it into a shuffle for you.  Like `_mm_set_ps(v[1], v[1], v[0], v[0])`.  In general that won't always compile to good asm, but worth a try with `clang -O3` (clang has a very good shuffle optimizer).  In this case both GCC and clang figure out how to do that with one `unpcklps xmm0,xmm0` (https://godbolt.org/z/o6PTeP) instead of the disaster that was possible.  Or the reverse with `shufps xmm0,xmm0, 5`  (5 is `0b00'00'01'01`).

(Note that indexing a `__m128` as `v[idx]` is a GNU extension, but I'm only suggesting doing it with clang to find a good shuffle.  If you ultimately want intrinsics, check clang's asm then use the intrinsic for that in your code, not a `_mm_set`)

Also see the SIMD chapter in Agner Fog's optimization guide (https://agner.org/optimize/); he has a good table of instructions to consider for different kinds of data movement.  Also https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simd.html has a good visual quick-reference, and https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ lets you filter by category (Swizzle = shuffles), and by ISA level (so you can exclude AVX512 which has a bazillion versions of every intrinsic with masking.)

See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info for these links and more.

---

If you don't know the available instructions well (and the CPU-architecture / performance tuning details), **you're probably better off using C with intrinsics**.  The compiler can find better ways when you come up with a less efficient way to do a shuffle.  e.g. compilers would hopefully optimize `_mm_shuffle_ps(v,v, _MM_SHUFFLE(1,1,0,0))` into `unpcklps` for you.

**It's very rare that hand-written asm is the right choice, especially for x86.**  Compilers generally do a good job with intrinsics, especially GCC and clang.  If you didn't know that `unpcklps` existed, you're probably a long way from being able to beat the compiler easily / routinely.

Comment: I've found that Clang and GCC vary wildly in efficiency of SIMD instruction selection on x86 (with Clang generally outperforming). I would suggest checking the output of both compilers and likely using them as inspiration to roll your own (or choose best between the two). [Example of wild variance between the two I recently saw for icelake-client](https://godbolt.org/z/dP6Mo7)

Comment: @Noah: Yup, 100% agreed, always ask a compiler when you're looking for good options to get something done in asm.  (Or just use intrinsics, more maintainable and you're not going to beat the compiler without more experience.)

Comment: @Noah: Huh, interesting how GCC shoots itself in the foot for version_3, comparing into a mask, expanding back into a vector, then using `vpmovmskb`.  And then somehow failing to spot the `blsi` peephole.  AVX-512VL adds more ways to do things so that's new for compilers to sort out.

Comment: generally what it has seemed to me with GCC optimizing AVX512 instructions is that it arbitrarily chooses the mask variant but ignores the mask unless the user explicitly uses it. Not sure what up with it.